# Iterating through string backwards through iterator in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, iterator, range

I have this code:

```
var formatterIndex = hourFormattingPattern.endIndex
let formattingPatternRange = formatterIndex ..< hourFormattingPattern.startIndex
```

But I'm getting an error of bad access when the second line is called. Is there a way to specify a range that reverses through the string `hourFormattingPattern`? After the initialization, I'm doing this:

```
while !stop {
    //Do pattern matching and switching with string and replace char string
    formatterIndex = formatterIndex.predecessor()

    if formatterIndex <= hourFormattingPattern.endIndex || tempIndex <= tempString.endIndex {
         stop = true
     }

 }
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can iterative backwards with `for index in (hourFormattingPattern.startIndex ..< hourFormattingPattern.endIndex).reverse() { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't form a range from a larger number to a smaller one. Also, `endIndex` is not a valid index--it's one past the last valid index. You can, however, form your range forwards and then reverse it:

```
var formatterIndex = hourFormattingPattern.endIndex
let formattingPatternRange = hourFormattingPattern.startIndex..<formatterIndex

for formatterIndex in formattingPatternRange.reversed() where !stop {
    //Do pattern matching and switching with string and replace char string

    if formatterIndex <= hourFormattingPattern.endIndex || tempIndex <= tempString.endIndex {
        stop = true
    }
}
```

However, your logic may be off, because *all* possible values of `formatterIndex` are `<= hourFormattingPattern.endIndex`, and thus `stop` will be set `true` on the first run of your loop.